# Inconsistent output when rendering markdown with the node-markdown module

Tags: node.js, express, markdown

I'm trying to write a controller in `express` that takes some markdown and returns some HTML for forum posts.

I get the expected behaviour at the command line:

```
> var md = require('node-markdown').Markdown;
undefined
> md("\n\ndon't mind me\n====")
'<h1>don\'t mind me</h1>'
```

But then if I receive a `HTTP POST` request which according to Chrome has the following form data

```
raw:\n\ndon't mind me\n====
```

I receive this response:

```
<p>\n\ndon't mind me\n====</p>
```

It's not correctly identifying the `H1` tag.

Here's the code for parsing the markdown:

```
var md = require('node-markdown').Markdown;

var parseMarkdown = (function () {
return function (raw_md) {
    return md(raw_md);
}
}());
```

Here's my controller code:

```
app.post('/render_markdown', function (req, res) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var raw = req.body['raw'];
    res.send({ html: parseMarkdown(raw)});
});
```

Anyone got a clue what might be going on here? I've tried fiddling with escaping and unescaping when passing the input into the Markdown function and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: if you do a `console.log(raw)` what does it print out?

Comment: It prints out the expected raw string: `\n\ndon't mind me\n====`

Comment: can't seem to find any problems with this code. Is the `parseMarkdown` function in the same file or are you exporting it somehow?

Comment: It's in the same file. I wonder if maybe the version where I'm using express has some unicode characters coming through or something.

Comment: could be...does it work for other regular markdown like `###test` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send a string containing the json, instead of the actual object in the response. Try this:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({ html: parseMarkdown(raw)});
```

Comment: The thing is, it's not failing to send the message - the object is available on the client side, I can look up the string by its key in the object, it's just that verbatim - in the text of the response - it doesn't have the correct markup. It does have some markup - the wrapping `<p>` tag - but it's failed to parse the `\n====` into an indication of a `h1` tag.

Comment: ok, my mistake then...I didn't know you can send JSON that way. It's very strange, if you say the REPL command gives the proper result and the string is the same in the server, there's no reason why the parse method shouldn't work on the server. Can you confirm it's working for other regular markdown strings like `###hi` or `**test**` ?